# Optional ROS package (and catkin) dependencies

Tags: ros, catkin, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there (going to be) support for specifying optional dependencies for ROS packages in both package.xml and CMakeLists.txt?

Rationale: I do some optional resource generation during the build process (optional robot parts), and then I want to merge all these generated resources in a common resource. So this common resource needs to be built only after the resource generation for the parts has finished. But I still need to preserve the optionality of the various parts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217719/optional-ros-package-(and-catkin)-dependencies/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2015-09-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no planned support for optional dependencies. Here is some related reading:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/83726/catkin-optional-build-dependency/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/202251/policy-on-run_depends-for-external-optional-binary-packages/

**Edit: Adding example of looking for dependencies conditionally in CMake**

First let me explain the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` mechanism.

This:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS foo bar baz)

message("Libraries: ${catkin_LIBRARIES}")
```

Is the same as:

```
find_package(foo REQUIRED)
find_package(bar REQUIRED)
find_package(baz REQUIRED)

message("Libraries: ${foo_LIBRARIES};${bar_LIBRARIES};${baz_LIBRARIES}")
```

So any variable which starts with `catkin_` will be the aggregate of the items you passed as `COMPONENTS`.
Therefore, you can find package things one at a time and act accordingly:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS required_dep1 required_dep2)

set(MY_SRCS src/main.cpp ...)
set(MY_LINK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(MY_LINK_LIBRARIES ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

find_package(optional_dep1)

if(optional_dep1_FOUND)
    list(APPEND MY_SRCS src/optional_dep1_code.cpp)
    list(APPEND MY_LINK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${optional_dep1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    list(APPEND MY_LINK_LIBRARIES ${optional_dep1_LIBRARIES})
    # Anything else you need to do to enable use of the optional dep, like add definitions
    add_definitions("-DUSE_OPTIONAL_DEP1=1")
endif()

include_directories(include ${MY_LINK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package()

add_executable(my_exec ${MY_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(my_exec ${MY_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

You can imagine how you could conditionally do just about anything based on the result of `optional_dep1_FOUND`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-09-15**:
That's a pity. Imagine the combinatorial explosion of "workaround" packages which should model all combinations of optional equipement on our robot (at least 5 pieces -> 32 packages)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-15**:
There is nothing to stop you from writing your `CMakeLists.txt` such that it tries to find additional deps which are not listed in the `package.xml` and use them if found. They just won't be installed before building on the build farm. But at least from source you can install them and use them.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-15**:
If you want to include the "optional" deps on the build farm but make them optional when built from source, you can put everything in the `package.xml` and write your `CMakeLists.txt` such that it doesn't fail if a dependency is not found. The build tools will not have a problem, but others might.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-15**:
For instance, `rosinstall_generator` and `rosdep` will try to fulfill all dependencies in the `package.xml` and it would be up to the user to narrow down that list when building from source.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-15**:
If you want to use the "recommended" pattern that .deb files allow for, you can do what I suggest here: http://answers.ros.org/question/202251/policy-on-run_depends-for-external-optional-binary-packages/?answer=202260#post-id-202260 and patch the release repository.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-09-15**:
The solution with custom CMakeLists.txt rules seems to be clean and I like it. However, I'm no CMake geek, so could you please point me to the right set of commands? Something like `find_package(catkin QUIET COMPONENTS optional_dep); if (optional_dep_FOUND) add_dependencies(...); endif()` ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-15**:
You'd need to `find_package(...)` each optional item independently, I'll update my answer with an example.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-09-21**:
Thanks, I tested this solution and it works well. The only thing is I use `find_package(optional_dep QUIET)` so that CMake doesn't issue a warning when the package is not found.